# How to optimize the performance of a MySQL view

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I have a view defined as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_data_summary AS
SELECT
    a.b_id AS b_id
    b.txt_field AS b_txt_field
    a.txt_field AS a_txt_field
    SUM(a.amount) AS amount
FROM
    a JOIN b
WHERE
    a.b_id = b.id
GROUP BY
    a.b_id, b.txt_field, a.txt_field
```

Table `a` has 650,000 records, while table `b` has 3,200 records. There is an index on `a.b_id`. The tables grow at a rate of 1,500 records per day on table a, and 50 records per day on table b.

When I run a select on the view, it takes about 25 seconds. I'm concerned that as the tables continue to grow in size, the performance of this query is going to rapidly degrade.

What can I do, to either the individual tables, or to the view itself, to improve the performance?

**EXPLAIN**

Running `explain` on the select above yields the following output:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          b   ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    3078    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE          a   ref b_id    b_id    4   b.id    134
```

**TABLE DEFINITIONS**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `b` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `txt_field` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `txt_field` (`txt_field`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `b_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `txt_field` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `txt_field` (`txt_field`),
  KEY `b_id` (`b_id`),
  KEY `new_index` (`txt_field`,`b_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more proper to post this on the DBA site?

Comment: I suppose - I'm not a member of that site yet, and I've seen similar questions being posted here.

Comment: Did you execute `EXPLAIN <select from your view>` yet? If yes post results in textual form in your question, if no do it and post results.

Comment: What are the data types and lengths of `a.txt_field` and `b.txt_field`?

Comment: they are both varchar fields

Comment: See above. I added those indexes, but it did not appear to have any impact on the performance of the query.

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query or view, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: Andy - the indexes were listed, but I put the table definition there so you can see. Row counts and the Explain results were in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Add an index on `(b_id, txt_field, amount)` and create the view with:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_data_summary_2 AS
SELECT
    a.b_id AS b_id
    b.txt_field AS b_txt_field
    a.txt_field AS a_txt_field
    SUM(a.amount) AS amount
FROM
    a JOIN b
      ON
    a.b_id = b.id
GROUP BY
    a.b_id, a.txt_field ;
```

If you had a `foreign key` in `a(b_id)` that `references b(id)` you could also try changing the `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` and compare performance. In that case, the view could also be defined with:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_data_summary_4 AS
SELECT
    a.b_id AS b_id
    (SELECT b.txt_field FROM b WHERE a.b_id = b.id) AS b_txt_field
    a.txt_field AS a_txt_field
    SUM(a.amount) AS amount
FROM
    a 
GROUP BY
    a.b_id, a.txt_field ;
```

Comment: There is a foreign key relationship - I will try redefining the view using the sub-select instead, and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You're using InnoDB - glad you mentioned that.

Here's a checklist:

- Optimize your table

This will reorganize your table on your server for quicker input/output

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE b;
OPTIMIZE TABLE a;
```

Check out more about InnoDB Optimization at: [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb.html)

What I don't understand is why you have created a key for each and every single column of yours, that is a little redundant - as you could just tie in multiple columns as a single key (composite index) - especially if you are only going to compare a single column to another column from another table. Ideally, you created an index in the same order as the group by as well.

Also logically, they would only be comparing a single key index when using the GROUP BY rather than sorting through each key and then placing them next to the correct value.

- a.b_id - could be a [FOREIGN KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)
- Lastly - check your memory, consider using InnoDB's buffer options as well.

Hope that helps. To assist others, if one of these assisted you, leave a comment which one had the biggest impact.

Comment: The reason for all the indexes is because I'm only showing a small subset of the columns involved in the original tables - however, the actual tables have many columns which are not indexed. I will try the suggestions you made, and comment as to impact of each, when I get into the office.